# Fullcalendar agendaWeek - display timed events vertically

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to display timed events which are starting-ending at the same time (for example 8:00-9:00) vertically instead of horizontally in AgendaWeek/AgendaDay views.

Some pictures of agendaWeek view to clearly explain what I am trying to achieve:

**picture how it is now**
[image]
**What I want to do**
[image]

In second picture I changed .fc event { position: initial } in fullcalendar.css file.
However this way it does not add events to its time rows.

Basically what I want is a simple table with x-axis:day; y-axis:time and display events there like in a month view.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you find a solution for this? I would be more than happy to start a bounty if somebody thinks he can solve it for me.

Comment: See a very good solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112606/fullcalendar-io-how-to-display-one-event-per-line-in-agendaweek-then-mix-all-in/44246084#44246084).