# Fullcalendar Horizontal Events in AgendaWeek

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In my fullcalendar, when events have same time with each other, it becomes thin/tight event blocks - just like this:

[image]

which makes it hard to read (much harder if there are many events happening).

I have stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112606/fullcalendar-io-how-to-display-one-event-per-line-in-agendaweek-then-mix-all-in) and this is the I got when I add the customized CSS:

[image]

I tried to modify the CSS to this

```
.some-classname {
    width: 100%;
    height: initial !important;
    position: relative;
    left: 0% !important;
    margin-right: 0% !important;
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

However "meeting 1" is missing, and upon checking, it is overlapped by "meeting 2"

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I am using fullcalendar v.3.10.2.

Comment: FWIW I disagree with this as an approach. Your idea makes it look like the events occur one after the other, but they don't - they all start at the same time, which is why they are all side by side, starting in line with the 1:00 marker on the grid. If you make them start at a different point in the grid then it defeats the point of having an accurate time grid. As you can see, from your "what I'm trying to do" picture, an event starting at 1:00 appears at 2:00 on the grid. That makes no sense and will be confusing for users.

Comment: I agree that the width can be an issue when there are multiple events side by side, but you can always make your calendar wider for those with larger screens. You can also set the [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotEventOverlap) setting to `true`, to fit more into the available space. Also consider whether you actually need a [resource-aware view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/vertical-resource-view) to split the different events into different lanes - e.g. if they occur in different rooms or different teams, something like that.

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment @ADyson! will no longer proceed with this approach