# Fullcalendar, how to display events as rows in timeGrid view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to display "bookings" in back-office, I need to implement week overview (**timeGridWeek**), but it looks very odd in comparison to monthly view where all events displayed as rows for each day.

Different "bookings" can start and end in same time, I want to display them as separated entries, each in individual row (hour cell should expand vertically). End time can be ignored, only start time matters.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nibrev/12vLxn8k/16/) example of configuration and sample data.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  let now = new Date();

  if (calendarEl) {
    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      views: {
        timeGrid: {
          type: 'timeGrid',
          expandRows: true,
          allDaySlot: false,
          // slotDuration: '00:30:00',
          // slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
          // duration: {days: 7}
        }
      },
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      // eventMinHeight: 100,
      // slotEventOverlap: false,
      // eventMaxStack: 1,
      expandRows: true,
      selectable: false,
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      initialDate: now,
      eventDisplay: 'block',
      editable: false,
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Event 1',
          start: '2023-09-05T03:00:00',
          end: '2023-09-05T04:30:00',
          className: 'test'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 2',
          start: '2023-09-05T03:00:00',
          end: '2023-09-05T04:30:00',
          className: 'test'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 3',
          start: '2023-09-05T03:00:00',
          end: '2023-09-05T04:30:00',
          className: 'test'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 4',
          start: '2023-09-05T03:00:00',
          end: '2023-09-05T04:30:00',
          className: 'test'
        },
      ],
      stickyFooterScrollbar: 'false',
      height: 'auto',
      buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'chevron-left',
        next: 'chevron-right',
      },
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek prev,today,next'
      },
      eventContent: function (info) {
        return {html: info.event.title};
      },
    });
    calendar.render();
  }
});
```

Here are already was [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112606/fullcalendar-io-how-to-display-one-event-per-line-in-agendaweek-then-mix-all-in) with answer, but it not applicable for modern version of Fullcalendar. I also attaching screenshot, what I want to achieve.
[image]

Thanks.